# Dynamically target specific DIV´s with unique ID in Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Say that I have more than 100 forms on one page (I know it is a lot, but neccesary in this matter) and I have a Ajax that submit each forms without reloading the page it is in, and Show/Hide a DIV on callback from jQuery on success and error, how do I:

1 : Target the specific DIV ID in the jQuery
2 : Make sure that it submit the specific form and only this form (not validating on required fields from other forms)

JS Code:

```
<script>
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {

  var dataString = $(this).serialize();
  let response_div = $("[id^='response_div_']")

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "update_userdata.asp",
    data: dataString,
    success: function() {
      response_div.html("<div id='message' style='background-color: #28a745;'></div>");
      $("#message")
        .html("<font style='color: white;'>Løn Information er nu opdateret <i class='fas fa-check-circle'></i></font>")
        .hide()
        .fadeIn(1500, function() {
          $("#message").append(
            ""
          );
        });
    }
  });

  e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="response_div_initials_1">
</div>
<form name="Initials2"  id="Initials2" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="UserID" id="UserID" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="ColumnToUpdate" id="ColumnToUpdate" value="InitialsColumn">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="input-box">
    <label for="Initials" id="Initials">Initials</label>
    <input type="text" name="Initials" id="Initials" minlength="3" maxlength="3" class="text-input" required/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" form="Initials2" value="Submit">Send</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>


<div id="response_div_EconomyColumns_1">
</div>
<form name="EconomyColumns1" id="EconomyColumns1" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="UserID" id="UserID" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="ColumnToUpdate" id="ColumnToUpdate" value="EconomyColumns">
<fieldset>
<div class="input-box">
  <label for="lonnr" id="lonnr_label">lonnr</label>
  <input type="text" name="lonnr" id="lonnr" minlength="3" class="text-input" required/>
</div>
<div class="input-box">
  <label for="debnr" id="debnr_label">debnr</label>
  <input type="text" name="debnr" id="debnr" class="text-input"/>
</div>
<div class="input-box">
  <label for="orgnr" id="orgnr_label">orgnr</label>
  <input type="text" name="orgnr" id="orgnr" class="text-input"/>
</div>
  <button type="submit" form="EconomyColumns1" value="Submit">Send</button>
</fieldset>
</form>

<div id="response_div_initials_2">
</div>
<form name="Initials2"  id="Initials2" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="UserID" id="UserID" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="ColumnToUpdate" id="ColumnToUpdate" value="InitialsColumn">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="input-box">
    <label for="Initials" id="Initials">Initials</label>
    <input type="text" name="Initials" id="Initials" minlength="3" maxlength="3" class="text-input" required/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" form="Initials2" value="Submit">Send</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<div id="response_div_EconomyColumns_2">
</div>
<form name="EconomyColumns1" id="EconomyColumns1" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="UserID" id="UserID" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="ColumnToUpdate" id="ColumnToUpdate" value="EconomyColumns">
<fieldset>
<div class="input-box">
  <label for="lonnr" id="lonnr_label">lonnr</label>
  <input type="text" name="lonnr" id="lonnr" minlength="3" class="text-input" required/>
</div>
<div class="input-box">
  <label for="debnr" id="debnr_label">debnr</label>
  <input type="text" name="debnr" id="debnr" class="text-input"/>
</div>
<div class="input-box">
  <label for="orgnr" id="orgnr_label">orgnr</label>
  <input type="text" name="orgnr" id="orgnr" class="text-input"/>
</div>
  <button type="submit" form="EconomyColumns1" value="Submit">Send</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

I tried different variations of $("[id^='response_div_']") but havent had success with any attempts I have tried.

Comment: Shouldn't the `e` in the callback `function(e) ` hold a reference to that specific form?

Comment: Oh my god, what a stupid mistake, thanks Mr. Brickowski, in my example the form name for both initials had the same id and name, and same goes for EconomyColumns .. the issue with the form target offcause went away when I gavethem unique names and id´s .. So it seems that only the targeting the DIV´s issue is left. :-)

Comment: Want to know more on the business requirement. A form and a response div is a one to one mapping and not share to others? A form submitted, the message should only show on the associated response div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 100+ form, I would suggest [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for one event listener listens multiple forms.

If those `response_div_` are just for displaying message to a specific form, but not for storing data, I suggest you to not setting a unique id to them. Instead, I move the response div under the form and set it with `form_response` class so you know which div to update.

I also put the styling into `<style>` so you don't need to handing css inside the script.

I usually don't write html within string literal. To have a icon after the response message, you can offload it to CSS which makes your script neater. Check the `form_response::after` style. [Font awesome has an article on that.](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements)

p.s. you need to fix the submit button and form name. There are 2 `EconomyColumns1` and `Initials2` form.

```js
$('html').on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var dataString = $(this).serialize();
  // obtain the submitting form with e.currentTarget
  // then search the tree down for div with class form_response
  let responseDiv = $(e.currentTarget).children('div.form_response');

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://6049aeb7fb5dcc001796a5ad.mockapi.io/foobar", // mock api for testing
    data: dataString,
    success: function() {

      $(responseDiv)
        .html("Løn Information er nu opdateret")
        .hide()
        .fadeIn(1500, function() {
          // what is this line for?
          $("#message").append("");
        })
        // wait 5 second
        .delay(5000)
        // fade out
        .fadeOut(1500);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.form_response {
  display: none;
  background-color: #28a745;
  color: white;
}

.form_response::after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  content: "\f058";
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form name="Initials2" id="Initials2" action="">
  <div class="form_response"></div>
  <input type="hidden" name="UserID" id="UserID" value="1"> <input type="hidden" name="ColumnToUpdate" id="ColumnToUpdate" value="InitialsColumn">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="input-box">
      <label for="Initials" id="Initials">Initials</label> <input type="text" name="Initials" id="Initials" minlength="3" maxlength="3" class="text-input" required />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" form="Initials2" value="Submit">Send</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>



<form name="EconomyColumns1" id="EconomyColumns1" action="">
  <div class="form_response"></div>
  <input type="hidden" name="UserID" id="UserID" value="1"> <input type="hidden" name="ColumnToUpdate" id="ColumnToUpdate" value="EconomyColumns">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="input-box">
      <label for="lonnr" id="lonnr_label">lonnr</label> <input type="text" name="lonnr" id="lonnr" minlength="3" class="text-input" required />
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
      <label for="debnr" id="debnr_label">debnr</label> <input type="text" name="debnr" id="debnr" class="text-input" />
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
      <label for="orgnr" id="orgnr_label">orgnr</label> <input type="text" name="orgnr" id="orgnr" class="text-input" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" form="EconomyColumns1" value="Submit">Send</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>


<form name="Initials2" id="Initials2" action="">
  <div class="form_response"></div>
  <input type="hidden" name="UserID" id="UserID" value="1"> <input type="hidden" name="ColumnToUpdate" id="ColumnToUpdate" value="InitialsColumn">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="input-box">
      <label for="Initials" id="Initials">Initials</label> <input type="text" name="Initials" id="Initials" minlength="3" maxlength="3" class="text-input" required />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" form="Initials2" value="Submit">Send</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>


<form name="EconomyColumns1" id="EconomyColumns1" action="">
  <div class="form_response"></div>
  <input type="hidden" name="UserID" id="UserID" value="1"> <input type="hidden" name="ColumnToUpdate" id="ColumnToUpdate" value="EconomyColumns">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="input-box">
      <label for="lonnr" id="lonnr_label">lonnr</label> <input type="text" name="lonnr" id="lonnr" minlength="3" class="text-input" required />
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
      <label for="debnr" id="debnr_label">debnr</label> <input type="text" name="debnr" id="debnr" class="text-input" />
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
      <label for="orgnr" id="orgnr_label">orgnr</label> <input type="text" name="orgnr" id="orgnr" class="text-input" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" form="EconomyColumns1" value="Submit">Send</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Brilliant Mr. Brickowski, that was it, that was the solution I was looking for, it totally works as it should, THANK YOU!! :-) .. I have even added a SetTimeout for the DIV now to fade out :) .. Can I ask you one more thing, eventhough I have marked your answer as accepted? .. If I would like to have the html("") text to be dynamically filled depending on the form I am submitting, how would I do that? :-)

Comment: BTW: <i class='fas fa-check-circle'></i> is an font icon from FontAwsome.com ;-)

Comment: You want to display a double quote character to the responseDiv? Just like any other character but with a escape sequence \. `$('body').html("this is a double quote: \"")`

Comment: @Stkol76 You can make use of `delay()` followed by `fadeOut()` to queue the subsequent animation. It is handy instead of handling the timer by your own.

Comment: Thank you @Mr Brickowsky, that did the tricks :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want...?

the HTML

```
<h2>Form 1</h2>
<form>
  <div class="message"></div>
  <input type="text" name="name-a">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<h2>Form 2</h2>
<form>
  <div class="message"></div>
  <input type="text" name="name-b">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

then jQuery

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
   
   e.preventDefault();
   
   let data = $(this).serialize();
   let msgBox = $(this).find('.message');
   
   $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'update_userdata.asp',
     data: dataString,
     success: function(){
       msgBox.html("Put your html message here that will display according to the submited form");
       // Once we have the message we show the message box
       msgBox.css('display', 'block');

     }
   });
   

});
```

and some CSS

```
.message {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 4px;
  display: none;
}
```

the working demo https://jsfiddle.net/jozsefk/1yw7c9x3/ Please note, that this is just an example to show you how to do it and you must adapt this to your code.
Also this will display your input name and value if exists based on a form submited.

Comment: This is almost it yes, exept that I need to be able to throw HTML to it, and not the data from the input, and that I need to give the message info from i.e data-content and not from name .. I have just played a little with it, and changed .text to .html, but that did not give me the result I need.

Comment: As i wrote above that is an example, your ajax request result would be an html then you add msgBox.html('<p>Hello World!</p>'); <p>Hello World!</p> is the result of your ajax. From your example <div id='message' style='background-color: #28a745;'></div> this is the msgBox.html() content ALSO YOU CAN USE ONE ID PER PAGE see <div id="message" ...>

Comment: I have edited the jQuery part to understand better what I mean.

Comment: Sorry josefk, I simply cannot get it to work .. I have for the last 3 hours tried using your full Ajax script, and also parts (the 3 lines for msgBox) and placed in my initial script, tried using both class and ID for message but and a lot of combinations, but what ever I do I cannot get it do display the DIV in any way, and when I use your full Ajax code it will not submit to the DB - last might be part of why I cannot get your Ajax to work since I simply does not get a 'success' back .. I will post what I have now in code in new Question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I have last tried:

```
<div class="message" style="background-color: #28a745;"></div>
</div>
<form name="Initials1"  id="Initials1" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="UserID" id="UserID" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="ColumnToUpdate" id="ColumnToUpdate" value="InitialsColumn">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="input-box">
    <label for="Initials" id="Initials">Initials</label>
    <input type="text" name="Initials" id="Initials" minlength="3" maxlength="3" class="text-input" required/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" form="Initials1" value="Submit">Send</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>


<script>
$('form').submit(function(e){
   
   e.preventDefault();
   
   let data = $(this).serialize();
   let msgBox = $(this).find('.message');
   
   $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'update_userdata.asp',
     data: dataString,
     success: function(){
       msgBox.html("<p>Hello World!</p>");
       // Once we have the message we show the message box
       msgBox.css('display', 'block');

     }
   });
});
</script>
```

The message CSS from you is still in the doc aswell